# Calculate the number of biweekly pays in 1 month

Tags: excel, google-sheets

To create a monthly budget in Google Sheets, biweekly pay needs to be calculated. Some months there are three paydays and some there are two. Paydays are every second Wednesday night.

The below formula worked previously, and now it does not.

Before being rounded, the formula calculates to `=ROUNDDOWN(1.14)*1000` which multiplies the pay amount by one except there is never only one payday in a month. This month there are two pay days, 14/09/16 and 28/09/16.

```
=ROUNDDOWN((EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-(MOD(DATE(2016,8,31)-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),14)+DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)))/14)*1000
```

Where is the error in my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this formula:

```
=(INT((EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-DATE(2016,8,31))/14)-INT((EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)-DATE(2016,8,31))/14))*1000
```

It calculates all the paydays from the end of the current month back to your date of 8/31/2016 and subtracts all the paydays from the prior month back to the same date.

In march of 2017 it will give the correct 3 paydays.

Comment: My apologies for not explaining, the date of 31st August 2016 is the last known pay date. Using 17/08/16 or 3/08/16 (also previous pay days) gives the same answer. I would like to calculate from a known pay date.

Comment: @c0dejunk1e remember that if this works please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.